# Modifying GUIDE ListBox outside its Callback function

Tags: matlab, listbox, matlab-guide

I have developed a GUI using GUIDE. It has several dropdown lists. I want to be able to reset/restore the state of the lists to some original/initial state when I press a push-button. The way I attempted to do it is by using the set command as follows:

```
set(handles.z_height, 'Value', z_index);
```

The above command is located within the callback of the reset button. However, when I run this code it returns the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> set
Invalid handle object.

Error in ==> GUI_LCL_LCL>reset_Callback at 906
    set(handles.z_height, 'String', num2cell(z_height));

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> GUI_LCL_LCL at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==> @(hObject,eventdata)GUI_LCL_LCL('reset_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

What I’m I missing?

Comment: Check here: [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91773-why-do-i-get-an-error-message-saying-invalid-handle](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91773-why-do-i-get-an-error-message-saying-invalid-handle)

Comment: You might have to set yourhandle handles as a global variable. Matlab will not find it otherwise.